# Computer Screen Showing Lines, not even hitting bootloader

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, bootloader

Here is what the laptop looks like **right** after hitting the power button (only a second delay to get to this point). This is all it shows, and goes to nothing else.

[image: laptop example]

Laptop would not display on an external display, however holding the `Power Button` + <kbd>D</kbd> showed various colours correctly as it is suppose to.

The laptop is now opened. How should I troubleshoot this problem and fix it?

Side Note: It will not even boot from CD drive. I tried a Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: If this laptop has ejectables like battery and CD Drive, try re-seating them and try again.

Comment: @wbogacz didn't help.

Comment: Check your RAM. If you have two sticks, pull one out, try to boot. if it works, switch sticks and see if it still boots. Bad ram can cause all kinds of problems. A good first place to check before a full tear down. Might even want to see if you have any spare known good sticks to try just in case they are both bad.